# Sub query to retrieve previous fields for variation records grouped by a ParentUUID

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I am currently running MySQL workbench 8.0 and have been asked to retrieve the previous value specific to that record by date. Here is an example of the database I am working with:

[image: Example of the data I am working with]

The row "PreviousTransactionValue" is what I am trying to retrieve. So far I have Ranked each record with its parent and variation record by using:

```
    CASE WHEN ParentTransactionUUID IS NOT NULL
     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentTransactionUUID  ORDER BY MAX(TransactionDate), 
     TransactionNumber DESC)
    ELSE
     0 END AS TransactionOrder
```

The above assigns a ranking to each record by partitioning the ParentTransactionUUID - "TransactionOrder".

My thought process around how to achieve this is to create a derived table where for that ParentTransactionUUID find the transactionOrder then the PreviousRank order to return the value?
I'm just stuck on how to write it.

Thanks

Comment: Please check stackoverflow guide for asking question.

Comment: An image of sample data table is a big no no. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table` and post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68417041/edit) along with a few rows of data sample. Post the desired output as well.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I can't, I am a new account and cannot post images. Due to my nature of work also I am unable to share the data.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'm saying that you shouldn't post your sample data table as image. It's hard for us to copy & paste that if we want to assist you. Also , I didn't ask you to share real data. Just any fake data that correspond to your table structure and from that how would you want the output to look like. By the way, in case you didn't know `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will only show your create table syntax.. it won't include your data in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
LAG(TransactionValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentTransactionUUID  ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC)
```